# Unity TinCan missing an assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

So I'm using the following lib for .NET TinCan integration

[TinCan .NET](http://rusticisoftware.github.io/TinCan.NET/)

Now I want to create a `Unity3d` package that can connect to my `LRS`.

So what I did was use `NuGet` to install the package:

[image]

However my `Unity` console throws the following error:

> Assets/UnityTinCan/TinCanController.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name `TinCan' could not be found. Are you missing an
>   assembly reference?

The file in question is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TinCan;
namespace UnityTinCan
{
    public class TinCanController
    {
        public RemoteLRS LRS = new RemoteLRS(
            LRSConfig.host,
            LRSConfig.username,
            LRSConfig.password
        );
    }
}
```

However, my IDE is not throwing any errors.

Can anyone tell me whats going on?

Comment: Have you added TinCan to your Unity3d project? This error may happer because you've added link to TinCan in your IDE, but project itself is compiled by IDE but by what unity is set to use (mono or il2cpp)

Comment: @vmchar if i attempt to add TinCan as a folder to my assets the error disapears but then it says it cant find Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Then also add Newtonsoft.Json to your unity3d project

Comment: @vmchar if i do that then it says it contains functions not supported by .NET 4.0

Comment: @vmchar Assets/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/JavaScriptUtils.cs(57,23): error CS1644: Feature `null propagating operator' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification

Comment: you can try using unity 2017.1 with .net 4.6 setup

Comment: i am using 2017.1.0f3

Comment: so the only solution is to fix Newtonsoft.Json sources to compile with Unity's .net version

Comment: @vmchar thats about 82 cases :(

Comment: Take a look here  https://github.com/SaladLab/Json.Net.Unity3D that's newtonsoft json for unity